# How did the purported 2008 decoupling of emerging markets pan out?

Tags: macroeconomics, economic-history

One opinion voiced (in *The Economist*) around the 2008 recession [was that](https://www.economist.com/finance-and-economics/2008/03/06/the-decoupling-debate):

> Decoupling does not mean that an American recession will have no impact on developing countries. That would be daft. The point is that their GDP-growth rates will slow by much less than in previous American downturns.

In hindsight, how did this pan out?

I seem to recall that some Eastern European countries, e.g. [Estonia](https://www.eestipank.ee/sites/default/files/publication/en/AnnualReport/2009/_17.pdf) (and actually [all 3](http://www.ijhssnet.com/journals/Vol_2_No_19_Special_Issue_October_2012/21.pdf) Baltic states) had a much worse recession in the aftermath than the US did (~15% contraction of GDP for 2009 compared to 2.5% for the US). But how did this alleged decoupling from the US economy fare on average for the emerging markets in aftermath of 2008?